# data corrupt while storing in char ***

Tags: c

I am trying to implement `DFA` `(Deterministic Finite Automaton)` in C, so far I'm trying to store the transitions of `DFA` in the variable `transitions` as shown in the following code.But for some reason, the data in the `odd` indices of `transitions` is getting corrupted, I think it's because of the way I used delimiting `\0`?. I've attached the output following to the code, Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_INPUTS 10
#define MAX_INPUT_SIZE 5
#define MAX_STATES 20
#define MAX_STATE_SIZE 5
#define MAX_ID_SIZE 100
int get_id(char str[],char str_arr[][MAX_STATE_SIZE],int len)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(str,str_arr[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    char inputs[MAX_INPUTS][MAX_INPUT_SIZE];
    char states[MAX_STATES][MAX_STATE_SIZE];
    char*** transitions;
    char temp_state[MAX_STATE_SIZE],temp_input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE],id_string[MAX_ID_SIZE],cur_inp[MAX_INPUT_SIZE],cur_state[MAX_STATE_SIZE];
    int i,j,k,numinps,numstates,row_id,col_id;
    printf("Enter number of input states: ");
    scanf("%d",&numstates);
    printf("Enter number of input symbols: ");
    scanf("%d",&numinps);
    transitions = (char ***) malloc(sizeof(char**)*numstates);
    printf("Enter the input states: \n");
    for(i=0;i<numstates;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %s",&temp_state);
        strcpy(states[i],temp_state);
    }
    printf("Enter the input symbols: \n");
    for(i=0;i<numinps;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %s",temp_input);
        strcpy(inputs[i],temp_input);
    }
    printf("Enter the transitions:\n");
    for(i=0;i<numstates;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<numinps;j++)
        {
            transitions[i] = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_INPUT_SIZE*numinps);
            transitions[i][j] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STATE_SIZE);
            printf("\n( %s , %s ) => ",states[i],inputs[j]);
            scanf(" %s",temp_state);
            strcpy(transitions[i][j],temp_state);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<numstates;i++)
        for(j=0;j<numinps;j++)
            printf("\n TRANSITION: ( %s , %s) =>  %s\n",states[i],inputs[j],transitions[i][j]);
    printf("Enter a String to find ID: ");
    scanf(" %s",id_string);
    strcpy(cur_state,"q0");
    for(i=0;i<strlen(id_string);i++)
    {
        cur_inp[0] = id_string[i];
        cur_inp[1] = '\0';
        row_id = get_id(cur_inp,inputs,numinps);
        if(row_id == -1)
        {
            printf("Input symbol is not present in sigma");
            exit(0);
        }
        col_id = get_id(cur_state,states,numstates);
        strcpy(cur_state,transitions[row_id][col_id]);
        printf("\n---- %s => %s ----\n",cur_inp,cur_state);
    }
}
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: regarding lines like: 'scanf(" %s",&temp_state);'  temp_state is only 5 characters long, so the max input length is 4 (to allow for the termination byte appended by %s)  however, there is nothing stopping the user from entering 'abcde'  which will overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and perhaps a seg fault event.   Suggest: for each call to scanf() with a %s format parameter, to include a length modifier (in this case,  4)  Also, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) from scanf() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: When calling malloc (and family of functions)  1) sizeof(char) is always 1, has no effect on the returned value, and just clutters the code   2) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() (it is already a 'void *' so can be saved to any other pointer)

Comment: before this line: 'exit(0);'  and any other exit point in the program, pass all the allocated memory pointers to free().  Otherwise there will be (lots of) memory leaks.

Comment: the function: main() is declared to return an 'int'.   While 'modern' compilers will allow there being no 'return value;' statement.  Not supplying such a statement is very poor program practice.  (when no return statement supplied, then the current contents of (I forget which register) will be returned, which will cause the OS to think the program exited with a failure condition.)

Comment: @user3629249 , Thank you for your suggestions :) , I do all these after  I finish up the program usually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be the problem:

```
for(i=0;i<numstates;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<numinps;j++)
    {
        transitions[i] = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_INPUT_SIZE*numinps); // <- this line
        transitions[i][j] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STATE_SIZE);
        printf("\n( %s , %s ) => ",states[i],inputs[j]);
        scanf(" %s",temp_state);
        strcpy(transitions[i][j],temp_state);
    }
}
```

You are allocating `transitions[i]` in each loop of `j`, use this instead:

```
for(i=0;i<numstates;i++)
{
    transitions[i] = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_INPUT_SIZE*numinps);
    for(j=0;j<numinps;j++)
    {
        transitions[i][j] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STATE_SIZE);
        printf("\n( %s , %s ) => ",states[i],inputs[j]);
        scanf(" %s",temp_state);
        strcpy(transitions[i][j],temp_state);
    }
}
```

In `j` loop you realocate whole `transitions[i]` which causes only last string will be stored